# How to display errors on a page without validation Summary?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project in which i read multiple field from an excel file and save them in db.How to show multiple errors messages on a page if user enters wrong value. Aspose.cells is used for reading data.My code is

```
    public List<Data> ImportFromExcel(Stream bytes, out bool isFine)
    {
        isFine = true;
        DateTime DOJ;

        List<Data> list = new List<Data>();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        Workbook workBook = new Workbook();
        workBook.Open(bytes);

        Worksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheets[0];
        try
        {
            dt = workSheet.Cells.ExportDataTable(0, 0, workSheet.Cells.MaxRow + 1, workSheet.Cells.MaxColumn + 1, true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isFine = false;
            ShowMessage("Your file has some invalid formats of data. Please review it and try again.", MessageType.Error, true);
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            int i = 1;

            foreach (DataRow reader in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (reader["LetterId"].ToString().Length > 75)
                {
                    isFine = false;
                    ShowMessage("In Row Number " + i + " Letter Id cannot exceed 75 characters.", MessageType.Error, true);
                    return null;
                }
                if (reader["Subject"].ToString().Length > 75)
                {
                    isFine = false;
                    ShowMessage("In Row Number " + i + " Subject cannot exceed 75 characters.", MessageType.Error, true);
                    return null;
                }
                 .
                 .
                 .
```

Show message method shows only single error message.

Comment: Suggestion: Add your error messages in a `List<string>` variable before calling `ShowMessage`. Finally, combine the error messages (`string.Join`) and call `ShowMessage`

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty list of strings, and then each time you encounter an error just add it to the list. Then once you have all the errors in your list, you can just do this:

```
        string allErrors = string.Empty;
        foreach (string err in errorList)
        {
            allErrors += err + "<br />";
        }
        if (allErrors != string.Empty)
        {
            ShowMessage(allErrors);
        }
```